# Symfony2 in-depth help needed for shopping cart as a whole

Tags: php, arrays, magento, symfony, twig

Id like to begin by saying that this shopping cart is not created by me, however it is changed in the way that I need and I understand most of the code and how it works and all the functions and methods are mine. The things I dont understand I hope to learn with you guys. This is going to be a long and in-depth post but I hope you will be as much interested in teaching me as I am in learning from you.

**Background:**

I have an e-commerce project in which I need to create a shopping cart for the products to be stored in. The process goes like this: indexpage(with all the products)->detailspage(details of the selected product)->summary(The shopping cart with selected products).

**The questions:**

I have a few questions commented in my code that are just simple questions regarding the shopping cart that I didnt create. I hope you can help me understand them.

**The problem:**

There are a few problems with the code, but I probably can figure out everything once the biggest problem is fixed:

When I add my first product to the cart it works like a charm, I am able to display the prices, discounts and everything I need and I even can delete it. After adding the second product the loop doubles. That means that instead of Product1, Product2 I am getting Product1, Product2, Product1, Product2. The same goes with 3 products and etc. This is the biggest problem. Theres one more strange thing. Doing dump on both cart and products(you will learn about them later) I am getting only 2 values in arrays the way it supposed to. That means the problem is somewhere in the twig?

Now with the code. This is the controller of my indexpage. In here i simple fetch all the products and get my cart with session:

```
public function indexAction()
    {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findAll();  // I get the products

            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

            if (!$session->get('cart')) {           
                 $session->set('cart', array()); // QUESTION#1 : I am checking if the cart is empty? If ith empty I am making it empty again?
            }

               return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:index.html.twig',  array(
               'products'=>$products       
               ));

    }
```

The second controller is for my product details page. This is were the fun starts:

```
public function viewAction($id)
    {

        // fetch the cart   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($id);  // I am getting the product based on the id.

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        $cart = $session->get('cart', array()); // I am getting the cart

        // check if the $id already exists in it.
        /**if ( $product == NULL ) {  // QUESTION#2: I am checking if the 

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
        }
        else { **/
        if( isset($cart[$id]) ) { // Checking if the product is already in the cart. If so, increase the product by 1

            $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock(); // I am getting the quantity of that prouct

            if( $qtyAvailable >= $cart[$id] = $cart[$id] + 1 ) {
                $cart[$id] = $cart[$id] + 1;; 
            } else {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
            }
        } 
        /**else {
            // if it doesnt make it 1
            $cart = $session->get('cart', array()); // IF not just 
            $cart[$id] = 1;
        }
            **/

        $session->set('cart', $cart);
        return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_details.html.twig',  array(
               'product'=>$product
        ));
    }
```

The final controller is the summary with all the selected products:

```
public function summaryAction()
    {
            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

            // fetch the information using query and ids in the cart
            if( $cart != '' ) {

             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                foreach( $cart as $id => $quantity ) {  //QUESTION#3 For each product in the cart I am setting a new key and a value?
                                                        // and then im creating a new array where I store the products ids?
                          $productIds[] = $id;

                } 
            if( isset( $productIds ) ) // QUESTION#4 What am I checking here?
                {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findById( $productIds ); // I am getting all of the products in the cart by their id?
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig', array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }  //QUESTION#5 What is going on with these renders?

               return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
            'product' => $product,
                    ));
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }
            }
```

Finally this is how I try to display the cart in my twig:

**UPDATE**

I found the problem to the item doubling however I dont know how to fix it. So the problem is in my twig. If i remove the loop `{{ for key in cart }}`, it fixes the doubling, so this loop is bad. However I need that loop to be able to remove items from cart... Maybe there is some other way??:

```
{% if product is defined %}

            {% for key in cart %}  /// this loop causes the problem.

              {% for info in product %}


                <tr>

                  <td> <img width="60" src="" alt=""/></td>

                  <td>{{ info.model }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>{{ info.price }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.discount }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.value }}</td>


                  <td>{{ info.getFinal }}</td>


                </tr>

 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Cart dump:

```
array:3 [▼
  12 => 3
  10 => 1
  11 => 1
]
```

Product dump:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => Product {#668 ▼
    -id: 10
    -model: "Test1"

  }
  1 => Product {#757 ▼
    -id: 11
    -model: "Test2"

  }
  2 => Product {#858 ▼
    -id: 12
    -model: "Test3"
   }
]
```

Comment: How many keys do you have in your cart ?(The first loop in your twig file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to give my suggestion / opinion on some areas in your code. This might help you to further investigate the cause of your issue (duplication) and hopefully expand your level of understanding about Symfony 2.

**Questions 1 :**
Yes, you are setting the session variable `cart` to empty by calling `$session->set('cart', array())`. (Actually it will remove the `cart` session variable from the Session storage)

**Question 2 :**
Yes, you are checking whether entity `$product` returned any result or not. 
`if ( $product == NULL ) {` . (I'd use === instead of ==) . Also you can simply do like this `if (!$product) {` and it's valid.

**Not a Question :** I'd alter this `if( $cart != '' ) {` with `if($session->has('cart') && count($session->get('cart')) > 0 ) {` inside your function `summaryAction()`.

Just an advice from the experience. If you are performing an operation like this `$cart[$id] = $cart[$id] + 1` , do not fill the `$cart` array with the `id` of the `Product` table. Because when you are accessing products from the `Product` table with the values filled in the `$cart` array, you will experience unexpected situations such as Product not found. Simply because you are increasing the id by 1 in your code and that value might not exist in the table. (Hope I am not missing anything here. The reason I assumed like this was you have been using the same `$id` to access a record from the `Product` entity as well to fill up the `cart` session variable)

**Question 3 :** This situation perfectly matches with my above explanation. In here you are iterating through the `$cart` array assuming that values inside the `$cart` array reflects the id's of the `product` table which might not. Otherwise, there's no issue with the iteration.

```
foreach( $cart as $id => $quantity ) {  //QUESTION#3 For each product in the cart I am setting a new key and a value?
                                                    // and then im creating a new array where I store the products ids?
                      $productIds[] = $id;
            }
```

**Question 4 :** In here, `if( isset( $productIds ) )` you check whether `$productIds` variable is set and is not NULL. Since you are only setting the `$productIds` variable (which is an array) only if the there are ids stored in the `cart` session variable, this (`$productIds`) will not get declared / set if the `cart` session variable is empty.  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

**Question 5 :** In here,

`return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
            'product' => $product,
                    ));`

what you do is return a twig to the response, so it can render what's in the twig file. `product` is the twig variable which expects at the twig file (`MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig`). So, in this case, it uses this to iterate through the products, as you might have understood by now.

I hope this will help you at least up to some extent. I'd rather prefer if any other Symfony 2 developer can further enhance my reply if necessary. Many thanks. Cheers!!!

**Update :** I think I found the issue here. In the twig you are having a nested for loop. First it will iterate through the whole items in `cart` session and for each iteration (item in cart) it iterates what's in the `product` which will cause the duplication. So what you can do is a simple check like this, before you peform the operation.

```
{% for key in cart %}  
          {% for info in product %}
                         {% if key == info.id %}
                             // do your bits here
                         {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Like I said I will only be able to change my code on Thursday I hope it will help me with the duplication!

Comment: Ho @Dominykas55 check the (edited) update area in the answer above. Thanks :)

Comment: Hm, for some reason the code in the if statement doesnt excecute. If I add all the code there he just shows the cart empty. Does that mean that the cart keys and the products id dont match? I made dumps in my post, the ids look the same but not in the same order. I dunno if that can be the problem.

Comment: Hi @Dominykas55. That's interesting. If id looks the same, then there must be a blank white space at the beginning / end of key in `cart` session variable I guess (highly unlikely with info.id). So, you might trim before compare `{% if key | trim == info.id %}` . However, at first place you shouldn't be increasing the `cart` id, value (cart[id] = cart[id] + 1), so it can cause such issues. By the way, order doesn't matter, because you can always order `products` by writing a simple DQL. Cheers!

Comment: As you must've understood by now, the `key` and `info.id` must match with each other because you are filling the `cart` session variable with the same product id :)

Comment: Thank for the respone. What do you mean by saying i shouldnt increate the cart id? How else can I increase my cart? Btw, the trim didnt help.

Comment: Hi @Dominykas55 . If you are filling the `cart` variable with the product id's why would you increment it ? Because id's of product table will never be the same (assuming id is the primary key). So, just filling the `cart` with appropriate product id will be sufficient. Later, you can take the count of the items in the `cart` session variable to get the number of items in the cart. Isn't that so ? Also, when you increase the `id = id + 1`, how do you guarantee that `id` is an actual `id` of the product table ? Hope you got my point. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hey. @Anjana Silva. Maybe we could continue our discussion here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76613/shopping-cart-problem